# Given time intervals determine if a person could attend all meetings

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task** is taken from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/meeting-rooms/)

> *Given an array of meeting time intervals consisting of start and end times `[[s1,e1],[s2,e2],...]` `(si < ei)`, determine if a person could
>   attend all meetings.*
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[0,30],[5,10],[15,20]]
> Output: false
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[7,10],[2,4]]
> Output: true
> ```

**My imperative solution:**

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} intervals
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var canAttendMeetings = function(intervals) {
  intervals.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0]);
  for (let i = 1; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    if (intervals[i][0] < intervals[i - 1][1]) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
};
```

**My functional solution:**

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} intervals
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var canAttendMeetings = function(intervals) {
  return intervals
    .sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
    .flat()
    .every((x,i, src) => i % 2 === 0 || src[i + 1] === void 0 || src[i] < src[i + 1]);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions look quite sufficient to solve the task. I will say that the functional solution will likely be slower, not only because it is functional but also because of the call to `.flat()` and iterating over twice as many elements.

Correct me if this is incorrect, but the call to `.flat()` could be removed if the call to `.every()` was changed to a condition similar to the condition in the imperative solution:

```
.every((x,i, src) => i === 0 || !(src[i][0] < src[i - 1][1]));
```